# Hibernate's property hibernate.default_schema is not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to add parameterized database name which is used in native queries 
I referred this URL to implement
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-resolve-the-hibernate-global-database-schema-and-catalog-for-native-sql-queries/
I have tested in stage and testing environemnt and everything is working fine
except database name is missing.
Below is my code

**application.yml**

```
hibernate:
show_sql: true
format_sql: true
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hbm2ddl.auto: false
default_schema: student
```

**SummitRepository.java**

```
@Query(value = "select * from {h-schema}summit", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Summit> getActiveUpcomingSummitsForChannelIds();
```

**TestDbConfig**

```
public class TestDbConfig {  

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpa = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpa.setDatabasePlatform(env
                .getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateJpa.setShowSql(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql",
                Boolean.class));

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(datasource());
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpa);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.xxx.student.model");
        Map<String, String> jpaProps = new HashMap<String, String>();

        jpaProps.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        jpaProps.put("hibernate.format_sql",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        jpaProps.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        jpaProps.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        ***jpaProps.put("hibernate.default_schema",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.default_schema"));***

        emf.setJpaPropertyMap(Collections.singletonMap(
                "javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none"));
        return emf;
    }
```

**Hibernate background generated query**

```
 select * from summit
```

**Actual Output**

```
select * from summit
```

**Expected Output**

```
select * from student.summit
```

Database name is missing.
Where i am going wrong?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You state you are using Spring Boot, but why are you maniually configuring the `LocalEntityManagerFactory` and `DataSource`?  Also what exactly isn't working? The schema or databasename because those are different things.

Answer (score 1):

Specify default schema in your persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="yourSchemaName" />
```

Comment: `jpaProps.put("hibernate.default_schema",
                env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.default_schema"));` is exactly that

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  didn't get you.

Comment: I totally get what he says, but it is not the answer to this question

Comment: Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I fixed the issue my self
Actually i was mismatching hibernate properties.

Comment: I replaced 
"spring.jpa.hibernate.default_schema: student"
with
"spring.jpa.hibernate.properties.hibernate.default_schema: student"